# ExtJS - add floating panel on top of other panel

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJS 5. I need a container shown on top of other container and I don't know how to handle layouts to achieve this. The desired effect is:
[image]

Transparency is only for the issue purposes.

Using pure HTML it could be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
    <head>
        <title>a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0">
        <div style="height: 100%; background-color: #bbb">
            <div style="height: 50px; background-color: #888; padding: 15px; font-size: 20px; position: absolute; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box">
                Header
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 100%; padding-top: 50px; box-sizing: border-box">
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; position: relative">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus feugiat nunc mauris, et vestibulum purus luctus a. Nulla semper semper augue vitae varius. Integer sit amet lobortis leo. Ut lobortis volutpat molestie. Sed malesuada scelerisque cursus. Praesent ac placerat tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In ac augue elementum, aliquet purus suscipit, venenatis tellus. Sed varius arcu semper, tristique dui nec, scelerisque nibh. 
                    <div style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.8; z-index: 999; top: 0px; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 200px; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: green; padding: 15px; color: white;">
                        Panel on top
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Without the green container it could be simple VBox layout. I don't know how to add this green panel do show like this.

**edit**

I tried:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.mainview',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.MainViewViewModel',
        'Ext.panel.Panel'
    ],

    viewModel: {
        type: 'mainview'
    },
    itemId: 'mainView',
    layout: 'border',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'north',
            height: 100,
            itemId: 'headerPanel',
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'Header'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'center',
            html: '<h3>Lorem</h3>',
            itemId: 'contentPanel',
            title: 'Content'
        }
    ]

});
```

.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.SideContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.sidecontainer',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.SideContainerViewModel'
    ],
    viewModel: {
        type: 'sidecontainer'
    },
    floating: true,
    html: '<p>panel</p>',
    itemId: 'sideContainer',
    maxWidth: 150,
    minWidth: 150,
    width: 150
});
```

and I don't know what to do next. In console I put `Ext.create('MyApp.view.SideContainer').toFront()` and got the error `me.zIndexManager is undefined`.

Comment: When you say "panel on top" you mean zIndex, right? Not vertical align?

Comment: Yes - I mean z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a floating (see https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-floating) component in your container.
And then manage the positioning with *setPosition* or *alignTo* (witch need to be manage afterRender because it us el) or CSS

Comment: I know this but I can't handle :( I put in body question my trial code.

Comment: I've generated a quick [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14ls) with your code. It's working :). I comment the viewModel because I did not had the code (but you should uncomment). And to do this properly I suggest to create a panel and to override the ``afterRender``method instead of working with the ``listeners`` (but I did it like this just because it's was quicker). Hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Small edit in my Fiddle, I was using ExtJs 6, so I put the two version, you need a little bit a work to fix the positioning (In ExtJs 6 it's working like a charm...) but I put explicit comment (you need to work with ``alignTo`` and ``offsets``)